# Pandas group events by year

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to pandas but making progress...

I have the following `dataframe`:

[image: DataFrame]

I want to do a count on the number of events that have happened by Month/Year which I believe would produce something like the below

[image: Result of process]

I have tried the following based on the article located [here](https://www.wintellect.com/using-pandas-to-analyze-sales-data/)

```
group = df.groupby(['MonthYear', 'EventID']).count()
frequency = group['EventID'].groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
print(frequency)
```

I then get an error (using VS Code) that states:

> unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi'

I have had this before and it is usually when I have used the wrong case for my column names but I have verified they are correct.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `but my code doesn't work.` Why not.. do you see an error? Can you provide a **[mcve]** (e.g. with *text* data)?

Comment: Sorry your right, give me a few mins to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
frequency= df.groupby('MonthYear')['EventID'].value_counts()
```

See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for more details

Comment: I get this when I use your answer, <bound method SeriesGroupBy.value_counts of <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x0FDD2DB0>>

Comment: See [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for documentation

Answer (score 0):

You could try aggregation on top of groupBy     `df.groupby('MonthYear').agg({'EventID':'count'})`